# removeFromSuperview does not

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I have this code in a tvOS project

```
var loader: UIViewController!
```

. . .

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loader = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("appLoader")
        addChildViewController(loader)
        view.addSubview(loader.view)
        loader.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        getMovieData()
}
```

It adds the view controller as expected. Later, when I want to get rid of appLoader

```
queryOperation.completionBlock = {() -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // avoids autolayout error

            self.loader.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.collectionView1.reloadData()
            self.collectionView2.reloadData()

        })
```

`appLoader` remains behind the `collectionViews`.

I am new to Swift and iOS programming and presume I am missing something simple and fundamental. I am baffled -- not sure how to frame the question.

What I am trying to accomplish is show a very simple loader screen until the data from `getMovieData` is available. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassed to say that this was a simple fix.

After looking at app in Xcode's Debug View Hieracrchy , I realized there was an extra ControllerView also called appLoader associated with a segue. Once the segue code was deleted, all works as it should.